# Simplest way to set default entity value in separate partial class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, class, entity

This is beginning of my auto generated class Customer:

```
namespace Winpro
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Blocked = false;
        this.Code = "#00000";
        this.RuleId = 1;
        this.LocationId = 1;
        this.Contacts = new ObservableListSource<Contact>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;
    public System.DateTime Added { get; set; }
    ...
```

Why I can't extend class in this way.

```
namespace Winpro
{
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Added = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Looking for simple example of setting default values in separate class or override SaveChanges() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) is a class divided in multiple files. It is still a single class, and you can't have two constructors with the same signature.

You can try:

- Define a new constructor which takes parameter for DateTime
- Call the default constructor with `this`
- Assign the value to the `Added` property from the parameter

```
namespace Winpro
{
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer(DateTime parameterAdded)
     : this() //call the default constructor
    {
        this.Added = parameterAdded; //DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting error when I try to insert into db : `The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` While values set up in the default constructor works well

Comment: @Carlo, that seems like a different issue, you can see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608734/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o

Comment: Have read many Q&A, even ask my own like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295123/dbcontext-entity-framework-datetime-now-fields but I just don't get it. When I drag controls on my form and call customerBindingSource.AddNew() I want to set default values for fields. With values in default constructor everything work well but not for values defined in my second part of  partial class. Maybe I don't understand how to use your example?

Answer (score 0):

Go with a [partial method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx)

In the generated class

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Blocked = false;
        this.Code = "#00000";
        this.RuleId = 1;
        this.LocationId = 1;
        this.Contacts = new ObservableListSource<Contact>();
        AdditionnalInitialisation();
    }

    partial void AdditionnalInitialisation();
```

In your extension:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    partial void AdditionnalInitialisation()
    {
        this.Added = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot add anything into generated class because manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?